# How to call javascript function while JSF fragment loading(like body onload) in ADF

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

Since jsff file is a fragment in the web page; how can we call a javascript function on 'onload' of that jsff file.

Here is my use case -

- I have a taskflow with JSF fragments input.jsff & output.jsff.
- Flow of my taskflow is starts with input.jsff, which takes some input from user & output.jsff, which shows the output by processing the input data.
- Dropped this taskflow into a jspx file.
- jspx file has some javascript methods.
- I have to call one of the javascript method while loading output.jsff.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Can't you add the JS required for that page in output.jsff?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to execute a JS method post-page-load?

Comment: @HarshaR Yes, I am looking for the way to execute JS method on page load.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just call javascript method on page load use

```
<af:clientListener type="load" method="jsMethod"/>
```

hooked to the document tag.

If you need to do certain actions while loading some stuff, use taskflows with few views/steps instead. One step showes one thing, calls method or anything, then proceed to another view.

Answer (score 0):

Its always recommended avoiding the use of java script in `oracle adf` . If you are trying to invoke a method in java , using java script , you should probably try to add a method as a `default-activity` in the task-flow and invoke the taskflow .

If you could probably tell what you are trying to do with the java script we would be able to help you better.